# jQuery object in animate step function returning "undefined" on every function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to slightly modify a jQuery animation with the following code:

```
web_links.mouseenter(function() {
    var site = $(this).closest('.site');
    var image = site.find('.image').first();
    var offset = '-' + image.height();
    var caption = site.closest('.caption').first();                    
    site.find('.image').first().stop().animate({top: offset}, {
        duration: 400,
        step: function(curTop) {
            console.log(caption);
            console.log(caption.css("top");
            if (curTop < -191) {
                caption.css({top: curTop + "px"});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Oddly, caption seems to be a valid jQuery object that implements `css()`, but when I try to call the `css()` method on it, it returns `undefined`.  The same happens when I try `offset()`.

Does anyone have an idea of why this might be happening?  I've been racking my brain on this overnight, but it just doesn't seem to be making any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that this line isn't matching any elements:

```
var caption = site.closest('.caption').first();
```

Test the `.length` to find out for certain. If it's `0`, then that's the issue.

```
console.log(caption.length);
```

---

FWIW, you don't need `.first()` after `.closest()`, since `.closest()` returns a maximum of `1` element... hence the `"est"` part of the function name. ;-)

Comment: Yes!  Thank you!  I guess I've been looking at this so long I'm just not seeing it anymore.  closest should have been find.  Thank you so much!